# Add values of two rows and combine them into a single row in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My database structure looks somthing like below

`customer_id`        `product_id`  `quantity`

```
38             43          1

36             34          1

41             46          1

41             46          1

41             31          1
```

If the database has two `product_ids` with same value for the same `customer_id` then `quantity` have to be added and the rows must be combined to single row.

In the above case `customer_id` 41 has two `product_id` with value 46. So `quantity` of those two rows have to be added and two rows must be combined to single row.

I tried the below code, but it doesn't help me

```
$sql3 = "select customer_id,product_id from oc_cart where customer_id     = '41'";
$products=mysql_query($sql3);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($products)){
$cust_id = $rows['customer_id'];
$prod_id = $rows['product_id'];
}
$sql4 = "select  count(*) from oc_cart where customer_id =41 group by product_id "; 
$count=mysql_query($sql4);
```

Any help would be really greatfull.

Thanks.

Comment: `select customer_id,SUM(quantity) from oc_cart group by customer_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use Mysql function `SUM`:

```
$sql4 = "select  count(*), SUM(quantity) from oc_cart where customer_id =41 group by product_id ";
```